# France health insurance for non-EU resident with EU passport

Tags: france, health-insurance

I am an Australian moving to France on a scientific research visa for 2 years. My girlfriend (also Australian) is coming with me. She has a Dutch passport.

We are trying to work out what to do about health insurance for her. From reading the other answers on this website, I have surmised the following:

- Since she is not covered by another EU country she will be not be covered in France.
- If she gets a job working more than 60 hours per month she will be covered.

There is no guarantee she will be able to find a job straight away. Should she buy health insurance? Or is it possible to 3 months and apply for "couverture maladie universelle" or is that not applicable? Is there some way she could be covered by being my partner?

Comment: I'm pretty sure (but not sure enough for an answer!) that she will be covered by "state" insurance if she is your dependent. I don't even use CMU, as the normal securité sociale covers about half the expenses. She could also just buy coverage on a mutuelle for the rest if she doesn't have a job. In any case, keep copies of your tax returns for the past few years on hand for CMU, you'll need it.

Comment: Also, it took me 7.5 months to get my carte vitale (state insurance card) and you need to pay out of pocket until then, so be prepared for that unfortunately. You can get reimbursed later, though.

Comment: @lafemmecosmique Thanks for your responses. So even when I start working I'm not covered straight away either and need to get the "carte vitale"? Actually I'm still waiting for the convention d'accueil to arrive... Job starts in 4 weeks...

Comment: You're covered in the sense that if you are asked whether you have health insurance, you can legally say you are. But without the carte vitale, you have to pay out of pocket when you go to the doctor. You will get a tan piece of paper which you then keep until you get the carte vitale, and you get reimbursed for your previous visits at that point.

Comment: I was in the same position as you last year. It took a long time to get my convention d'accueil, and then it took a long time to get the visa. I was about three weeks late for work, which was annoying. Don't be surprised if you experience the same thing (don't buy plane tickets!!!) but I hope you don't have the same issues.

Comment: In case I was not clear: your doctor visits up until the point where you get the CV ARE reimbursed, but not until after you get the CV.

Comment: @lafemmecosmique Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately I think I will also be delayed! I thought you must have plane tickets already booked to receive the visa? Maybe that requirement is just for Australians.

Comment: For scientifique visa I don't remember that being a requirement. I didn't get mine until after because I was already super delayed. But I also applied from the UK and took a ferry, so perhaps they just assumed I'd be driving. I look forward to answering your next posts on getting carte de sejour or renewing your visa... things I know better !

Comment: @lafemmecosmique or OP, any of you would like to answer this question with your experience from hindsight?